# Logic - why isn't 'True' doing what I expect it to?

Tags: logic

I have the following code

```
test[variable_: 0] := Module[{},
   If[variable != True, Print["worked"]];
   ];

test2[variable_: 0] := Module[{},
   If[variable == True, Print["worked"]];
   ];
```

If I run

```
test2[True]
```

I get `"worked"` as I expect.

But if I run

```
test[]
```

I return nothing. Why is this the case?

Comment: `==` can't say anything about the equivalence between 0 and `True`. You want `=!=` and `===` instead.

Comment: Or just use `TrueQ`

Comment: try to evaluate `0!=True` and/or `0==True` and see what happens